# What do the collar symbols / insignia on this WW I Austrian soldiers uniform mean?

Tags: world-war-one, identification, uniform, austria-hungary

I am trying to determine what the rank or group of a soldier in a vintage photo is. I've been searching the internet for collar insignia but coming up short. I'd appreciate any help given. Additionally, if anyone can make out what the medals are or mean that would also be appreciated. The picture is known to have been taken 1918.

[image: Austrian soldier WW I]

Comment: The photo link seems broken.

Comment: The dating to 1918 is consistent with the [Karl Troop Cross](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karl_Troop_Cross) being worn (the medal on the right). I looked at an extensive list of collar patches ("Kragenspiegel") used by the Austo-Hungarian military during WW1, but could not find anything matching the motif shown here.

Comment: The medal on the left appears to be the commemorative medal "Pro Deo Et Patria" based on the ribbon pattern.

Comment: @njuffa Thank you so much!

Comment: Could the collar have a telegraph regiment badge?  It looks vaguely like https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Special_branch_badges_of_the_Austro-Hungarian_Army#/media/File:Zugsf%C3%BChrer_k.u.k._Telegraphenregiment.png

Comment: @kimchilover that looks a very plausible match to me

Comment: See also https://ww1photographs.wordpress.com/2012/09/30/an-austrian-telegraphist/

Comment: I think the medals are very on target. Thank you again to everyone! If you want to put it as an answer, I can upvote, and mark it as correct.

Comment: I wanted to add that I believe the telegraph regiment is correct.

Comment: And finally, the absence of any stars on the collar tab shows that the rank of the subject was private, the equivalent of the modern "OR-1" or "Rekrut".